# How to fetch page title name if document.title is not present

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I want to fetch page title name but document.title is not present. Instead of document.title the logic is written below:-

```
<title ng-bind="page.title()" class="ng-binding"></title>
```

I want to use javascript to get page title.

Comment: Call `page.title()`?

Comment: Once Angular has updated the `title` element, `document.title` should have the updated version. If it doesn't, something has gone wrong somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

> ...but document.title is not present

Once Angular has updated the `title` element, `document.title` should have the updated version. If it doesn't, something has gone wrong somewhere.

But:

> I want to use javascript to get page title.

Presumably you can get it from `page.title()` in your code. As you're making that available to Angular.

But:

If you really need to get it from the DOM instead, you *can*, but you shouldn't have to. Here's how:

```
var title = document.querySelector("title").innerHTML;
```